# Display the current line and column numbers in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just installed SP1 and now I don't see the text editor line and column number at the bottom of each source file in Visual Studio. Does anyone know how to turn this back on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried this?

Tools->Options->Environment->General->Show status bar

Comment: Thanks. that did it. I don't know why or how that got turned off. The upgrade to SP 1 did a job on my settings.

Comment: Weird, this is gone for me now even with that checked.

Comment: I do not find the Options in the Visual Studio for Mac(Enterprise). Any clue?

Answer (score 61):

If there's anyone with version 16.4.x or later wondering where it went, it got moved from the Status Bar to the bottom right of the editor window.

[image]

Please note that `Col` (column) is omitted from the status bar when it has the same value as `Ch` (character), as is the case when using spaces for indentation. Spaces will always increment `Col` and `Ch` together, whereas tabs will increment the `Ch` value by one while incrementing the `Col` value by whatever the tab width is set to be (e.g. 4).

##### Examples:

Tabs

```
--->--->Hello, World!
                     ^

Ch: 16    Col: 22
```

Spaces

```
········Hello, World!
                     ^

Ch: 22    Col: 22
```

If your cursor is at the tail end of the line, the `Ch` and `Col` values reflect the 1-indexed position denoted by the caret. `Col` would be omitted from the status bar in the second example.

Comment: Don't. I had to search online to find it, too; hence why I added this answer. Figured I'd shorten the search for someone. :)

Comment: I'm a moron. >_>

Comment: (For context, someone above me originally commented "boy do I feel dumb now," but later deleted it.)

Comment: well this was 1min of googling well spent. Now to see if selection length could be show, ah, of course MadsK https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ShowSelectionLength

Comment: They seem to have removed "Col" from the status bar for some reason in one of the last minor versions, which is far more useful to me than "Ch". Trying to figure out how to restore that.

Comment: Visual Studio Code was invented by people who've had to use visual studio for too long

Comment: Looks like they brought the "Col" column counter back in 16.8.

Comment: Final answer: the "Col" value appears when you're using tabs. When using spaces, Col and Ch have the same value, so the former is omitted. Since tabs are single characters that can have any effective character _width_, the Col value reflects that effective value.

Comment: Note, if you have many extensions using up space in the status bar, you may not see the line and column numbers; if your status bar is pretty full, try right clicking on items and hiding them until you have more space. [Update: this is true for VSCode; not sure about Visual Studio]

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone else has the same problem as me, I found that the line number and column didn't show up in the status bar until I hid some of the other information that was there - my extensions added a lot of items.

Right-clicking on the status bar gives a list of what's being shown there (excluding default stuff like columns, confusingly), and you can untick things to hide them. Untick enough, and line and column numbers should come back!

Related discussion in GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60537#issuecomment-974647350

Comment: It is the long progress message in my case.

Comment: An unusually long branch name, combined with a `Configure Excludes` notification, did it for me.