# Show cursor location in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Inside visual studio 2013, How to show the cursor position ("line, row" number) inside the editor window?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the row numbers in general to be visible?

Comment: it's allready visible in bottom of screen http://screencast.com/t/jwe2sn58R, and please try to describe your problem better, it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display the current line and column numbers in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697506/display-the-current-line-and-column-numbers-in-visual-studio-2010)